# Capacitor taping Vs straight leads

Tags: capacitor, dimensions

I can't understand what means in the datasheet below where it writes "Lead Space: Taping or Straight". With taping means that the leads have outside bend in order to increase the pitch between them? I didn't see it like that in a datasheet... only bend.

https://www.tme.eu/Document/2aee42c3e886fe56efb79da3a75be055/ABA0000C1209.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Panasonic Packing specifications](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/AAB8000/AAB8000COL58.pdf)

*With taping means that the leads have outside bend in order to increase the pitch between them?*

Not directly.  E13 (second row) has the same diameter (ø8) and pitch (F=3.5 mm) as E7, E9 & E12 (first row), but E13 has bent legs while E7, E9 & E12 are straight.  PCB layout would be different.

Like the datasheets say *Please refer to the page of "Taping dimensions"*, without including the actual page.  The compromise between the internet and a physical catalog.

In this case, you will have to contact the manufacturer for the appropriate data.

[image]

Straight legs are singles with equally cut legs.

[image]

The bend appears to be cut out of E13.